# Form not refreshing when query def updated

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that contains a subform which displays a datasheet view of a query. There is a button on the main form that when clicked will revise the query's SQL. When the button is clicked, the query is revised as expected, but the results do not update in the subform unless I close and reopen the main form.

I've tried to requery the subform and the main form. I've tried to refresh the subform and the main form. I've tried various combinations of the two, but nothing will update the data shown in the subform except closing and reopening the main form.

Any insights or suggestions?

This is the code that I have in the main form, and it runs when a button is clicked.

```
    Dim f as Form
    Set f = Me.frm_Subform.Form

    ' Update the query def
    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim sqlArray As Variant
    sSQL = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("myQuery").SQL
    sqlArray = Split(sSQL, "ORDER BY")
    sSQL = Left(sqlArray(0), Len(sqlArray(0)) - 3)
    sSQL = sSQL & " AND (STAFF.FULLNAME <> 'JOHN DOE') "
    sSQL = sSQL & "ORDER BY" & sqlArray(1)
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs("myQuery").SQL = sSQL

    ' Refresh the subform
    F.Requery
    Me.Requery
    F.Refresh
    Me.Refresh
    F.Repaint
    Me.Repaint
```

Comment: Still curious if anyone knows though why modifying the query and refreshing/requerying won't update the data in the subform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why modify query? Just to change the sort order? Build a form set for Datasheet view and apply sort criteria to the OrderBy property using DoCmd.SetOrderBy or

```
Me.OrderByOn = False    
Me.OrderBy = "your criteria"
Me.OrderByOn = True
```

And if you want to dynamically apply filter criteria, use code similar to the OrderBy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not just changing the sort order. The STAFF.FULLNAME <> 'JOHN DOE' is what's being added to the query with the actual name being dependent on what the user has selected. There are specific names that need to be excluded from the query based on user input.

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in right direction. Ultimately I used the filter property because I actually don't need any reordering: 'F.Filter = "STAFF.FULLNAME <> 'JOHN DOE'   F.FilterOn = True'